# OnScroll и видео HTML5

Tags: javascript, html5, видео

Доброго времени суток!

Ребята, установил скрипт: `codepen.io/ollieRogers/pen/lfeLc`

На демо, всё отлично работает, но у меня вообще печаль :[
Размер моего видео 80 МБ. Скролл получается с подгрузкой видео по текущей секунде.

Можно ли, как-то подгрузить всё видео полностью перед запуском сайта и скролла, чтобы убить загрузку видео при скролле? Иначе скроллить нормально не выходит, очень лагает...

Comment: А пример можно?

Comment: Не могу именно заставить браузер, сделать прелоад всего видео :[

Comment: пример видео? можно ссылку на codepen  с этим видео?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/meYGVm вот :]